# Type narrowing behavior not working depending on types involved

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

I have some type narrowing code that is causing a compiler error. When I make seemingly minor changes to the types involved in the narrowing, the compiler checks pass. The types are somewhat overlapping and involve optional attributes.

Are there any rules around type narrowing that might explain this behavior?

When the compile fails, the type that should have been narrowed does not appear to be narrowed -- in this case it is `Pet`. When you make a change to the types that compiles successfully, the type is `Pet & Dog`.

I hit this issue with production code, but have created a simple reproduction.

I checked previous TypeScript versions on the playground and the behavior seems to be the same, so I don't think this is new compiler behavior.

```js
interface Pet {
  name: string; // remove this or make it nullable and it compiles.
  isFriendly: boolean; // remove this it compiles.
}

interface Dog {
  name: string; // remove this and it compiles
  ownerName?: string; // make this non-nullable and it compiles
  // isHappy: boolean; // Add any other non-nullable property and it compiles
}

function isDog(value: any): value is Dog {
  return true;
}

// change the type here to Pet | Dog, or Pet & Dog and it compiles
const testAnimal: Pet = {} as any;

if (isDog(testAnimal)) {
  // when the compiler error occurs, the type of `testAnimal` is `Pet` here, not `Dog` and not `Pet & Dog`
  console.log(testAnimal.ownerName); // <-- Compiler error here: Property 'ownerName' does not exist on type 'Pet'
}
```

Here is a link to the [same code on the Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoTMg3gKGf5EOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5kB6Z5KCYgewDcUwAFsErIuUZMTgBrFMEwgArgBslcAEZKUcEABNkc5Ai7EADsE2UAdHgLCAYrQi6lATwpquXTdqat2nXn4hEQMjU3MIKxsAXxsbUEhYRBQAES46bBt8IlIKaloQRhY2Dm4+ZEFhZG09UOMzCyzRAHcQaAA5EggAfjyael82SRkK4MIuEABaRRV1TWrdfUwwhsimv2EACTgTEzdkDy8IH2LkAEEdPW0XUUFocamZ1Q0UEyguE2gwG5qlw3qIpQYnF8DAFCAEGBgBN9JQ0nQABQ8OBKBTkBYuACUFGRqNkInhmQI-jACigIAqUDRDGB+BsfgQAm0dCC-Bcn2QAmg-C4aAwyAAPsh4QAaUTidCYABkwvSC1qywBjXwRhA1AqkTAZxAwEkSgokuQAF5sNFqiJrjS6fhgDBkAjhPCEZBqNrdSjMZiiQQ-M0uRS7v9wppxNB3uIuAgEGTKGLA98OVw7S6tTq9bDkAADSWZzncsUgLiYTPw3O-QvFw0y0vrNh+pzIFxcBQSaRaQxMwo80Zsz4WxaBlYRDOUBRRyKUMFKONcirs-FZquyuiZpqqyhHSxKdLOzVuvWWLitDpdTGDZAAHkmk2QAGElfcw2I8xwDe9PlBvsgAORHtpQTpSG-ZAdC4SJxkwCAAA9hEwGEExQb9JW-WlkCAA)

Comment: My observations and 'thinkings'... It seems that there are no _additional_ properties in `Dog` that distinguish it from `Pet`; nullable ones don't count, because a type guard can't _always_ use them to distinguish between different types.

Comment: As they stand, the two types are not 'distinguishable enough', and because you marked `testAnimal` as `Pet`, it keeps that. Removing `isFriendly` from `Pet` makes it a supertype of `Dog`: any `Dog` is a `Pet`, and thus any `Pet` _could_ be a `Dog`; this then can type check. Removing `name` from `Pet` makes the two distinguishable, and the type guard can change the type of `testAnimal`. Adding a non-nullable property to `Dog` also makes them distinguishable.

Comment: Just ideas, I do not know for certain.

Comment: Re "not distinguishable enough": a type guard cannot determine if a 'maybe `Pet`' is a `Dog`, because the only way to check that would be to check for the presence of `ownerName`, which may not be present (but the value may still be of type `Dog`). You cannot go by the _absence_ of the `isFriendly` property, as objects are allowed to have excess properties (i.e., a `Dog` could legally have that property too).

Comment: Marking `testAnimal` as `Pet & Dog` obviously works, as it is a subtype of `Dog` (the type guard changes nothing). It seems that marking `testAnimal` as `Pet | Dog` works because TypeScript now knows that it could be either, and assumes the type guard will distinguish based on the nullable `ownerName` (with the chance of false negatives that comes with that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[User-defined type guard functions can only have predicate return types that narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) — they can't widen or otherwise arbitrarily mutate the type of the operand parameter.

Because of that, the predicate of your type guard needs to be an intersection of the input type and `Dog`, so:

```ts
declare function isDog<T>(value: T): value is T & Dog;
```

Using a [generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) for `value` is appropriate here in order to preserve that type information without needing to know it in advance (the compiler will infer it) — you could even [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it by another more broad type (as appropriate to your use case — even something like `object` is better than nothing).

Here's a complete example using the data you provided:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcDyAHWDUA2ACgE5zYCmJUAngDwBQiimiFAHlBWACbqJwARgCsK0ADRNEAaTadufRKXJVa0ijUnMAapIB8ACilDhALhZbE2MtnPTLAN0IgK2wjB6oocEgDEw5gZOBC7m4ADWYHAA7mAAlIgAvHqIwS6IMPy6DHHmJhn8rABkSqjUMIR0AEpiPjx09ojaeikA3lIkFFAgJEhGzMwAhAbW5BlIJgkAPlNSzGmu7p7efmAGBvkYiDUQdQ3iiBFRsXpxANqj2AC6cVJxANwMAL4MDDBgXCTAqBAUSl2IdrMMCoAC2FHM6CgJHeAHNHsxMr4YQoCDRzII4HACBRUGBHi83h8qN9fogACJwWGAqQg8GQ6FwhECWJUAByYIoAH4GTCwPDnq9QJA8EhMpTYXQACqGBbmKW5VLOP6ZRBSxAlCU05idbq9RD9Aa0ShwYBKkJ-RJWxAAIhMYigNo1JQWiEG1rAIAIBGdc1tdIoTve5vSRRKxooppDFAAdAGktabVC+bCnWG-WgsLh4CDiDZVDRDQNo5Zi3bWSQOeCbaWBkFlYrXark3CkikI1HXVbEraW-ya37bswHoKGLswFDEFwoQBBMAwUGEcxEAE91qIAPmG1zmA1grImCo9FTkjpJ6PN5mgziqkGadQHeLghxBJAxDj9DY2MEW-3x+EGMYjAdlOQeRAAHpwJYcI-WLYtIIAPS5QUgA)

```ts
function hasOptionalProperty<
  O extends object,
  K extends PropertyKey,
  V,
>(
  obj: O,
  prop: K,
  valueValidatorFn: (value: unknown) => value is V,
): obj is O & Partial<Record<K, V>> {
  return (
    !(prop in obj) ||
    valueValidatorFn((obj as Record<K, unknown>)[prop])
  );
}

interface Pet {
  name: string;
  isFriendly: boolean;
}

interface Dog {
  name: string;
  ownerName?: string;
}

function isDog<T>(value: T): value is T & Dog {
  return (
    typeof value === "object" && value !== null &&
    "name" in value && typeof value.name === "string" &&
    hasOptionalProperty(
      value,
      "ownerName",
      (value): value is string => typeof value === "string",
    )
  );
}

const testAnimal: Pet = { name: "Ani", isFriendly: true };

if (isDog(testAnimal)) {
  console.log(testAnimal.ownerName); // Ok
            //^? const testAnimal: Pet & Dog
}
```

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76638541/type-narrowing-behavior-not-working-depending-on-types-involved/76638827#comment135120267_76638827) @DarrylNoakes I'm not sure what you mean: the basic type guard is already separate from the full example. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I realized seconds later that that single line was actually everything that had changed, and deleted my comment.

Comment: I would really like is to hear your explanation of how changing the properties affect it. E.g., how do the relative positions of the two types re 'narrowness' change when changes are made as the OP stated? My comments were based almost solely on observation and intuition, smattered with some knowledge of TS internals and quirks re edge cases.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76638541/type-narrowing-behavior-not-working-depending-on-types-involved/76638827#comment135120325_76638827) @DarrylNoakes I'm not sure I understand your meaning, but if you refer to the OP's comments on the properties of the two interfaces, then I agree that seems very odd — someone with knowledge about the source code controlling evaluation of type guards in the compiler might need to answer that.